# Set jquery variable with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code. Its working for the play but the true and false are coming back as "true" and "false" I think.

```
var superslider_play = "<?php get_option_tree( 'superslider_play', '', 'false' ); ?>"
var superslider_pagination = "<?php get_option_tree( 'superslider_pagination', '','false' ); ?>"

$('#superslider_home').superslides({
    play: superslider_play, // Milliseconds for delay
    pagination: superslider_pagination
});
```

Ive tried using  `json_encode()` and `.replace("\"","\\\"")` but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably missed `echo`. Like this:  `<?php echo get_option_tree( ... `

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode(get_option_tree( ...`

Comment: And remove the quotes around it...should be: `var superslider_play = <?php echo json_encode(get_option_tree( ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hardcoded the quotes outside the `<?php ...?>`:

```
var superslider_pagination = "<?php get_option_tree( 'superslider_pagination', '','false' ); ?>"
// remove the double quotes -^-----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Assuming you want the result to be:

```
var superslider_pagination = true;
// OR
var superslider_pagination = false;
```

...by the time the browser sees it as JS.

Comment: Agreed. "false" would evaluate to true unless the plugin compared it as strings of course.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I was missing a ; after the <?php ...?> all good now without the quotes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the argument as bool (`true` or `false`) then no need to use quotes.
Instead of:

```
<?php get_option_tree( 'superslider_pagination', '','false' ); ?>
```

Try this:

```
<?php get_option_tree( 'superslider_pagination', '',false); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `<?php echo get_option_tree( 'superslider_play', '', 'false' ); ?>"` You are not returning the function. what is the data type returned by this object( Fro further more help) ?

Answer (score 0):

The values are coming out as "true" and "false" because you are using quotes before and after the php tags.

The following code:

```
var a = <?php echo "hola"; ?>   ; //  
var b = "<?php echo "hola"; ?>" ; //
```

Would output

```
var a = hola ;
var b = "hola" ;
```

About your attempt to use json_encode, maybe you forgot to do an echo.

```
<?php 
json_encode(true); // prints nothing
echo json_encode(true); // prints true
?>
```

In my opinion, the json_encode function should be used. 
In general, I would go with:

```
<?php
function get_option_tree($a,$b,$c) {
        return true;
}
?>
var superslider_play = <?php echo json_encode(get_option_tree( 'superslider_play', '', 'false' )); ?> ;
var superslider_pagination = <?php echo json_encode(get_option_tree( 'superslider_pagination', '','false' )); ?> ;

$('#superslider_home').superslides({
play: superslider_play, // Milliseconds for delay
pagination: superslider_pagination

});
```

This outputs:

```
var superslider_play = true ;
var superslider_pagination = true ;

$('#superslider_home').superslides({
play: superslider_play, // Milliseconds for delay
pagination: superslider_pagination

});
```